# Select columns matching names in a list

Tags: r

I have a data.frame

```
DF1
a.x.c b.y.l c.z.n d.a.pl f.e.cl
```

which consists of numeric columns

I also have a list

```
DF2
a.x.c  c.z.n  f.e.cl
```

which contains certain names of columns in DF2

I need to create `DF3` that would store only those columns of `DF1` which have matching names in `DF2`.
I have tried `which` to find indexes of columns i need. But problem that i have long name list of columns and `which` become useless.

Could you please help. Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Can you update the post with the `str(DF1)` and `str(DF2)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `intersect` to get the `names` that are common in both the datasets and use that to subset the columns of 'DF1' to create 'DF3'.

```
DF3 <- DF1[intersect(names(DF1),names(DF2))]
DF3
#  a.x.c c.z.n
#1     1     7
#2     2     8
#3     3     9
```

#### data

```
DF1 <- data.frame(a.x.c = 1:3, b.y.l= 4:6, c.z.n=7:9)
DF2 <- list(a.x.c= 1:5, c.z.n=8:15, z.l.y=22:29)
```

Comment: Is there any other way except intersect, cause it seems not working in some cases..Thanks.

Comment: @OlgaAnufrieva  Can you check whether there is any column names that is not matching with either of the two datasets, i.e. having trailing/leading spaces etc.?

Comment: No there are not. Basically `DF1` has many different columns but i want to pick only those which names are stored in `DF2`.

Comment: @OlgaAnufrieva  In that case, `intersect` should work fine.  Can you show an example where it is not working. i.e. show some strings that are common, but is not picked by the `intersect`

Comment: It returns `Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: @OlgaAnufrieva  Please share the column names in the data.frame and the names of the list.  Are you sure you are dealing with `data.frame` and a `list`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure I'm dealing with df and list and both of them contain some similarly named columns

Comment: @OlgaAnufrieva  I provided a reproducible example.  It works with that one.